# Alexa audio streaming skill http

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Can somebody explain how get http url to https url. I wont to put SHOUTcast stream radio url (http://live.narodni.hr:8063/stream) in Alexa skill but can't figure out how. :(

Skill work great with https url. but I want specific radio to use in Alexa skill

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use of HTTP vs HTTPS (secured HTTP) is determined by the owner of the service.

Unless the person that owns the service has a HTTPS endpoint, you'll be stuck running on HTTP.

Normally when you make a request a HTTP endpoint, it'll default to port 80 whereas HTTPS endpoints default to port 443.

From your URL above, it looks like the owner of live.narodni.hr opened up port 8063 and used that port to listen for HTTP requests. If you can find if and where they have a HTTPS port, then that should work.

You may want to to just try `https://live.narodni.hr/stream` which will use port 443 which is equivalent to `https://live.narodni.hr:443/stream`. For testing, some people like to use port 8443 too (8080 for http), so you can try `https://live.narodni.hr:8443/stream`.

TL;DR - it's up to the service owner to enable/support an HTTPS endpoint. Find that endpoint and you'll be good.